# Pra que serve a função breakpoint

Tags: python, funções

Estou me aprofundando em *python*, e como um bom iniciante curioso estou pesquisando as funções já presentes no *python* sem o uso de nenhuma biblioteca, quando me deparo com a função `breakpoint()`.
Não entendi muito qual a função dela em si, já que a linguagem do [site oficial](https://docs.python.org/3/) é muito formal e eu ainda não tenho a sagacidade de entender alguns termos...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A função embutida [breakpoint()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#breakpoint) chama o [Depurador de Código-Fonte Interativo Python](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pdb.html#module-pdb).
Esse depurador possui como características:

- Suporte a definição de pontos de interrupção condicionais e de passagem única na fonte.
- Inspeção de stack frame.
- Listagem de código-fonte.
- Avaliação de código Python arbitrário no contexto de qualquer stack frame.

Executando o exemplo:

```
a = "teste"
breakpoint()
print(a)
```

Quando o interpretador encontrar a função `breakpoint()` a linha de comando mudará para  o shell do depurador de código-fonte interativo Python(Pdb)

```
> /home/runner/2608v0dh5c5/main.py(3)<module>()
-> print(a)
(Pdb) ▉
```

Para saber a lista de comandos disponíveis digite nessa linha de comando `h` ou `help`:

```
> /home/runner/2608v0dh5c5/main.py(3)<module>()
-> print(a)
(Pdb) help

Documented commands (type help <topic>):
========================================
EOF    c          d        h         list      q        rv       undisplay
a      cl         debug    help      ll        quit     s        unt      
alias  clear      disable  ignore    longlist  r        source   until    
args   commands   display  interact  n         restart  step     up       
b      condition  down     j         next      return   tbreak   w        
break  cont       enable   jump      p         retval   u        whatis   
bt     continue   exit     l         pp        run      unalias  where    

Miscellaneous help topics:
==========================
exec  pdb

(Pdb) ▉
```

Para obter uma descrição de um comando em específico digite `help <nome_do_comando>`:

```
(Pdb) help next
n(ext)
        Continue execution until the next line in the current function
        is reached or it returns.
(Pdb) ▉
```

Os comandos elementares são:

- [`p expressão`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-p) : Avalia a expressão *expressão* no contexto atual e imprima seu valor. Exemplo:

```
(Pdb) p a
'teste'
(Pdb) ▉
```

- [`whatis expressão`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-whatis) : Exibe o tipo da `expressão`. Exemplo:

```
(Pdb) whatis a
<class 'str'>
(Pdb) ▉
```

- [`!declaração`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-!) : Executa uma `declaração` de uma linha. Exemplo:

```
(Pdb) !a = "não é mais um teste"
(Pdb) p a
'não é mais um teste'
(Pdb) ▉
```

- [`next`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-next) : Continua a execução até que a próxima linha na função atual seja atingida ou ela retorne. Exemplo:

```
(Pdb) next
não é mais um teste
--Return--
> /home/runner/2608v0dh5c5/main.py(3)<module>()->None
-> print(a)
(Pdb) ▉
```

Uma descrição completa dos comandos disponíveis no depurador de código-fonte interativo Python está  [disponível na documentação online](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).